# Multifilter SQL Server Pivot Count Query to table

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have never used SQL `Pivot` before and need help

I have the following data table (`wkYield`) in MS SQL Server 2012 which looks like:

```
| id  | Trav_num | Part_num | Reason_code | Scrap |  date    |
| 1   | 123123   | 400      | cw_iweld    |  1    | 1/1/2015 |
| 2   | 123122   | 400      | cw_iweld    |  1    | 1/1/2015 |
| 3   | 123124   | 400      | cw_iweld    |  0    | 1/7/2015 |
| 4   | 123124   | 400      | cw_iweld    |  1    | 1/7/2015 |  
| 5   | 123121   | 400      | cw_hole     |  0    | 1/1/2015 |
| 6   | 123121   | 400      | cw_hole     |  1    | 1/1/2015 |
| 7   | 123110   | 400      | cw_hole     |  0    | 1/7/2015 |
| 8   | 123110   | 400      | cw_hole     |  1    | 1/7/2015 |
| 9   | 123111   | 410      | cw_iweld    |  0    | 1/1/2015 |
| 10  | 123111   | 410      | cw_iweld    |  1    | 1/1/2015 |
| 11  | 123333   | 410      | cw_iweld    |  1    | 1/1/2015 |
```

I would like to use SQL to pivot the data to count the # of rows and display like the following:

```
| Part_num | Reason_code | Week | Scrap=1 Cnt(reason)| Scrap=0 Cnt(reason)|
| 400      |  cw_weld    |  1   |       2            |     1              |
| 400      |  cw_hole    |  1   |       1            |     1              |
| 400      |  cw_weld    |  2   |       1            |     1              |
| 400      |  cw_hole    |  2   |       1            |     1              | 
| 410      |  cw_iweld   |  1   |       2            |     1              |
```

And then the result should be placed in table `wkYieldSum`

I don't know for any given week number what the reason codes are (They change week to week but do have a lot of repeats.

All your help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this two ways one is `conditional Aggregate` another way is `Pivot`. I prefer Conditional Aggregate which more readable in my opinion

```
select Part_num,
       Reason_code,
       datepart(Week,[date]) as [Week],
       count(case when Scrap=1 then 1 end) as [Scrap=1 Cnt(reason)],
       count(case when Scrap=0 then 1 end) as [Scrap=0 Cnt(reason)],
From Yourtable
Group by Part_num,
         Reason_code,
         datepart(Week,[date])
```

Comment: Thank you Indian! Question - can you help me understand what the `(case when Scrap=1 then 1 end)` is?

Comment: What am doing is instead of counting every record am counting only when   `Scrap=1` else `NULL` which count aggregate will not consider to count. so only the rows with `Scrap=1` will be counted